# Controlling list of users who can access Synapse Analytics Serverless Pool/SQL Server by using 2 different Active Directory Groups

Tags: sql-server-2012, serverless, database-administration, azure-synapse

I have a below scenario

1. I have 3 Database roles(roles are pointing to Active Directory Groups) created in my database ( on Synapse Analytics Serverless Pool) . Each role represents the set of data that each role based users can access ( there are possibility to have overlapping users i.e, user 1 can be on Role 1 and Role 2 as well) . These AD groups are configured and made available to me - by a different team and I have a need to reuse the same AD Groups to grant access to the Synapse Serverless Pool/Instance that I am hosting to connect to ADLS Gen-2 and read the data(data exploration use case).
   example SQL scripts below

   SQL>>create user ADGroupA from external provider;

   SQL>>create role finance;

   SQL>>ALTER ROLE [finance] ADD MEMBER [ADGroupA ];

   SQL>>Grant select on SCHEMA ::finance to finance ;

   SQL>>GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ::SynapseManagedIdentity TO ADGroupA ;

Above listed scripts are executed for ADGroupB and ADGroupC
2. ADGroupA has 20 users, ADGroupB has 10 users, ADGroupC has 5 users
I have a requirement to grant access to Serverless Pool for 15 users ( by looking upon ADGroupA, ADGroupB and ADGroupC access for the 15 users to ensure - they get access to only required dataset/objects)
I have one challenge here in handling this scenario ; the user set of Serverless Pool are subset users from Role A , Role B and Role C ; so since I am creating my roles using ADGroupA , ADGroupB and ADGroupC - I am ending up with granting access to all 35 users ; but I am supposed to grant access only to 15 users ( who could be part of ADGroupD).

No - My question is - Is there a way to grant access by doing a INTERSECT of ADGroupA and ADGroupD for each roles that I create ?

[image]

Adding additional information on the expected outcome

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly. 
If you are able to have an AD Group D which consists of all 15 users that require access to Synapse SQL Serverless, why not granting them access directly?

AD-Group creating should be done outside of T-SQL code.

Comment: tried giving more information by adding a table in the actual thread - please check , if that provides more clarity .
 AD Group D - doesnt have any mapping of what tables should be displayed- it just has list of users , who should have access to. 
AD Group A, B and C are the ones - that can provide information on what tables should be visible. I cannot rely entirely on AD Group A listed users - as I need to grant access only if user has a entry in AD Group D as well